# add active/disable to child element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this simple selection that add 'active' class to the clicked element, and add 'disable' class to the element at opposite container.

My problem is how can move the `active/disabled` class from `.col-md-5ths` to their child element `.num`.

kindly check code.

Thanks.

```js
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        var otherSide = $(this).parent().hasClass('first-row') ? '.second-row' : '.first-row';
        var otherElement = $(otherSide).children().removeClass('disabled').eq($(this).index());
        $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? otherElement.addClass('disabled') : otherElement.removeClass(
            'disabled');
        $(this).hasClass('disabled') ? otherElement.removeClass('active') : otherElement.removeClass(
            'active');

    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        var otherSide = $(this).parent().hasClass('first-row') ? '.second-row' : '.first-row';
        var otherElement = $(otherSide).children().removeClass('disabled').eq($(this).index());
        $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? otherElement.addClass('disabled') : otherElement.removeClass(
            'disabled');
        $(this).hasClass('disabled') ? otherElement.removeClass('active') : otherElement.removeClass(
            'active');

    }

});
```

```css
.numChoice{
  display: block;
}
.num{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-md-5ths.active{
    color: green;
}
.col-md-5ths.disabled{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <br><br>
<div class="numChoice second-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to click the .num and change the parent class? Use `.closest`. 
Also DRY  - don't repeat yourself. You could use a toggleClass to not have to repeat the code.

Comment: You are abusing ternaries. Just use `otherElement.toggleClass(active) `

Comment: @mplungjan yes sir I'd like to add the active/disabled class to the `.num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shorter version

```js
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths > .num').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(".disabled")) return; // assuming you cannot click on a disabled
  $this.toggleClass('active');
  var act = $this.is(".active");
  var idx = $this.parent().index();
  var $otherSide = $this.closest(".numChoice").siblings(); // plural but only one
  var $otherElement = $otherSide.find(".num").eq(idx);
  $otherElement.toggleClass('disabled', act);
});
```

```css
.numChoice {
  display: block;
}

.num {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.num.active {
  color: green;
}

.num.disabled {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="numChoice second-row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5ths">
      <div class="num">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see update - I think this is a better version

Answer (score 1):

You can can achieve that in a more simplified way like the following:

```js
$('.numChoice .num').click(function() {
  $('.num').removeClass('active').removeClass('disabled');
  var parent = $('.first-row').has(this).length == 0?'.first-row' : '.second-row';
  var idx = $(this).parent().index();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(parent+' .num').eq(idx).toggleClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.numChoice{
  display: block;
}
.num{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active{
    color: green;
}
.disabled{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <br><br>
<div class="numChoice second-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```js
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths').click(function(index,el) {
    var thisind = $(this).index() + 1;
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('first-row')){
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
      $('.second-row .col-md-5ths').removeClass('disabled');
      $('.second-row .col-md-5ths:nth-child('+thisind+')').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('disabled');
      $('.first-row .col-md-5ths:nth-child('+thisind+')').addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

```css
.numChoice{
  display: block;
}
.num{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.col-md-5ths.active{
    color: green;
}
.col-md-5ths.disabled{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="numChoice first-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
  <br><br>
<div class="numChoice second-row">
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5ths">
    <div class="num">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/0m5adxec/1/) for you

```
$('.numChoice > .col-md-5ths').click(function() {
            var otherSide = $(this).parent().hasClass('first-row') ? '.second-row' : '.first-row';
        var otherElement = $(otherSide).children().removeClass('disabled').eq($(this).index());
      var $thisNum = $(this).children();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {    
        $thisNum.toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $thisNum.hasClass('active') ? otherElement.addClass('disabled') : otherElement.removeClass('disabled');
        $thisNum.hasClass('disabled') ? otherElement.removeClass('active') : otherElement.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('disabled');
        $thisNum.toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $thisNum.hasClass('active') ? otherElement.addClass('disabled') : otherElement.removeClass('disabled');
        $thisNum.hasClass('disabled') ? otherElement.removeClass('active') : otherElement.removeClass('active');

    }

});
```

Comment: thank you sir, almost there, when I click on the element it adds the `active` class to `.num`, this is correct. On the other container, the `disabled` class should be on the `.num` class too.

Comment: DRY: Don't repeat yourself